# Jenkins - Update / Edit the left panel label

Tags: jenkins, label, configure

I have configured Jenkins in my system and running fine. But I need to configure the jenkins UI.

a) I want to remove the "Jenkins" logo in header and instead of that I need to add "some text title".

b) I want to edit the left panel labels.

Ex. **Build history to Workflow history**, **My View to Workflow View** and **Build Executor Status to Workflow Executor Status**

Do we have any option to edit the html/config file directly or need to install any plugin to edit these labels. Thanks for your valuable time.

[image: jenkins left panel]

Comment: Question 1: Why you want to change the labels? Question 2: Do you just want to change the labels or change the functionality, hide the links etc?

Comment: I want to change only labels

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Jenkin's plugin simple theme:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin

You can personalize the CSS, the home page, the favicon. Pretty much everything that you need.

If you just need to do minor changes, you can have a look at https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/tree/master/src/site (site.xml). And the resources folder where the logo is stored.

Comment: Thank you. But how to update the left panel labels? Please help me.